# Alternative for Multiple ajax to get data rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 4 tabs on my page:

MY Queue | Today  | Followup | Upcoming

on page load i fire 4 ajax calls to get data from controller for all these tabs and once i get data i create list for each of the tabs.

But as ajax is asynchronous i get anomalies in my data, are there any better ways to achieve this.

i have 4 ajax calls similar to below call:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/opd_clinical_workflow/get_appointment_lists',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        current_date: current_date,
                        department_id: current_department,
                        doctor: current_doctor,
                        status: current_status,
                        source: "list",
                        q: $( "#search_appointment").val(),
                    },
                    success: function(res){
                        console.log(tab,res)
                        _this.updateMyQueueSummary(res,id,tab);
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
               });
```

updateMyQueueSummary:
Puts data in respective tabs

createSummaryAppointment:
Creates html for me and is called in updatesummary

Comment: If you need to load the data synchronously you can always make an ajax call within other ajax calls. Call another ajax inside the success function after the call to updateMyQueueSummary function.

Comment: i have tried that but this works well only upto 2 calls then agains it behaves unexpectedly

Comment: Can i data from multiple tables from the same method using json.jbuilder file

Answer (score 0):

Chaining AJAX is your best option:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "somewhere/1"
  })
  .always(function(reponse1) {
    //Do something with the response
    document.write("<p>1</p>");
    //Then call next part
    $.ajax({
        url: "somewhere/2"
      })
      .always(function(reponse2) {
        //Do something with the response
        document.write("<p>2</p>");
        //Then call next part
        $.ajax({
            url: "somewhere/3"
          })
          .always(function(reponse3) {
            //Do something with the response
            document.write("<p>3</p>");
            //Then call next part
            $.ajax({
                url: "somewhere/4"
              })
              .always(function(reponse4) {
                //Do something with the response
                document.write("<p>4</p>");
                //Now finalize it

                document.write("<p>Final</p>");
              })
          })
      })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Notice i am using `always` instead of `done` because i don't have anywhere to actually get data from.

Answer (score 0):

All the jQuery ajax methods return [promise objects](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/). This are kind of like an IOU note from a friend. You don't have the data now but it will be there at some point.

They are an extremely powerful tool if you want to avoid what is called "callback soup" where you nest ajax callbacks until the code is both unreadable and brittle.

```
var promise = $.ajax('/foo');
promise.pipe(function(data){
  return $.ajax('/bar?foo=' + data['foo']);
});
promise.done(function(data){
  // ajax call to '/bar?foo=' is complete
});
```

You can use [`jQuery.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to combine two promises. This is really useful when you want to fire two asynchronous ajax calls at once but you need the results of both to continue.

```
var calls = $.when( $.ajax('/foo'), $.ajax('/bar') );
calls.done(function(response_a, response_b){
 // both ajax calls are complete. 
});
```